# Time complexity involving product of variables

Tags: complexity-theory

If I have a function that takes n*g operations for input size n, but g << n, would I be able to say the function is linear wrt n?

Comment: wrt n? what does it mean?

Answer (score 2):

Not necessarily. For example, if `g = log(n)`, it is true that `g << n` yet `O(n * g)` is not linear in `n` (it is `O(n log(n))`).

Comment: that is not true if g is constant, for example. the OP hadn't stated nothing about the nature of g.

Comment: it's a user-chosen variable, but in practical cases g would be a constant the user decides which would be much smaller than n.

Comment: then it is linear, as you said. see [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Multiplication_by_a_constant).

Comment: thanks - i didn't know how to determine the complexity because g is meant to be a constant much smaller than n, but for example, the user could specify a value of g = n as well.  however, the nature of the function specifies that g be << n

Comment: read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/107165/big-o-for-eight-year-olds) answer and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10923764/time-complexity-of-a-program-which-involves-multiple-variables) answer.