# Computational Complexity

Tags: python, python-3.x, time-complexity, big-o

Suppose we have the function below:

```
def func(x, value_):
    assert 0 < x < value_
    while x < value_:
        x *= 2
```

Although `value_` can be arbitrarily large, the while loop is not infinite and the number of comparisons is bounded above by `value_`. Consequently, is it correct that this function has computational complexity of O(N)?

Comment: In general, big-O analysis isn't topical on StackOverflow. [cs.se] is the StackExchange site for theoretical computer science; our focus here is on practice, not theory, and we permit only questions about code that *doesn't work*. See [What to do with questions like these (big-O etc)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/296386/what-to-do-with-questions-like-these-big-o-etc) on [meta].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's `O(log n)` as `x` increases by doubling value toward `_value` for every execution. Try draw a graph of two lines you will see it.

Answer (score 1):

The time complexity will be `O(log(m/n, 2))`, where `m = value_` and `n = x`. Here, `log(i, 2)` represents the logarithmic of `i` in base 2.

Consider that if `x` is doubled, for a fixed `value_`, one less iteration is computed.

On the contrary, if `value_` is doubled, for a fixed `x`, one extra iteration is computed.

Comment: The base isn't really relevant; logarithms of `i` using different bases differ only by a constant factor. The usual convention is to just write `O(lg i)` to leave the base unspecified (though in practice it almost always arises from a base-2 logarithm, there's no great need to be specific).

Comment: There's also no need to specify the sizes of `value_` and `x` separately; the input size is simply the sum of the sizes necessary for `value_` and `x` (which is *not* the values of the two variables themselves, but a *logarithm*--you need *lg n* bits to specify a value *n*). Using a reasonable encoding, you end up with something like `lg value_ < n < 2 * lg_value` (give or take a constant number of bits), with the lower bound achieved when `x = 1` and the upper bound achieved when `x` is just less than `value_`. Either way, `O(lg n)` sufficiently describes the running time.

Comment: @chepner, I appreciate your first comment. On your second, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10923867/9209546) suggests you *should* consider multiple factors when considering time complexity. Regarding your comment, `the input size is simply the sum of the sizes necessary for value_ and x`, the "sum of the sizes" (`value_ + x` ?) has no significance to me. Can you explain further?

Comment: I would compare to how the complexities of graph algorithms is stated, in terms of number of edges (`m`) and number of vertices (`n`). Roughly speaking, a *sparse* graph has `m = O(N)` while a dense graph has `m = O(n^2)`. These types of graphs arise from real-world applications, and knowing whether an algorithm with complexity O(mn) is linear or quadratic in practice has real value. Here, though, you're dealing with something that at *worst* is O(lg n); is there any practical benefit to knowing that if `x` is large enough, the algorithm is really O(lg lg n) or even O(1)...

Comment: ... and is there a real-world problem where you actually have distinct classes of problems where such a distinction between `x` and `value_` arises naturally?

Comment: Also, mathematically, all functions take a single argument. That argument in this case is an encoding of two numbers; you can only measure complexity if you have a sufficiently precise definition of the size of the input, which in this case means the length of a non-trivial encoding of the two numbers. One possible method that suffices is to represent both values in a special binary form, where you specify `11` for each bit set in the value, and `00` for each cleared bit. ...

Comment: ... with a divider of `01` between them. As an example, `x=3` and `value=9` could be encoded as `11110111000011` (`11 11` for 3, `01` to divide the two, and  `11 00 00 11` for 9). This is only a constant factor larger than the naive encoding, so doesn't affect the asymptotic complexity of the function.